# Error: Unknown argument 'idea-shell'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm using **Intellij Idea community edition**. When  I run

```
new https://github.com/sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

or

```
new PlayFramework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

from **sbt shell**  it gives me following error :

```
Error: Unknown argument 'idea-shell' g8 0.7.2 Usage: giter8 [options] <template>   <template>            git or file URL, or github user/repo   -b, --branch <value>  Resolve a template within a given branch   -f, --force           Force overwrite of any existing files in output directory   --version             Display version number  
--paramname=paramval  Set given parameter value and bypass interaction EXAMPLES Apply a template from github
    g8 foundweekends/giter8 Apply using the git URL for the same template
    g8 git://github.com/foundweekends/giter8.git Apply template from a remote branch
    g8 foundweekends/giter8 -b some-branch Apply template from a local repo
    g8 file://path/to/the/repo Apply given name parameter and use defaults for all others.
    g8 foundweekends/giter8 --name=template-test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to how the sbt shell is implemented in the IntelliJ Scala plugin. Also the `new` command isn't really meant to be run from a live shell session.

Run `new` from the terminal instead:

```
sbt new https://github.com/sbt/scala-seed.g8
```

Comment: now I have another problem. when I run `sbt new PlayFramework/play-scala-seed.g8` it returns this error `org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:PlayFramework/play-scala-seed.g8.git: Connection timed out: connect`

Comment: are you able to clone the repository with regular git?

Comment: no I cannot. but I have configured proxy settings and disabled ssl verification. I managed to download it manually and built in intellij but I want this command to be available for future uses

Answer (score 0):

You should use it from the terminal like:
`sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8`

If you still have problems:

- Maybe you have to run it from a directory that is not a SBT project (no `build.sbt`)
- Of course you need `sbt` installed.